# Using RecyclerView.setAdapter from worker thread

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

Using **memberRecList** RecyclerView, I'm trying to list every member of a group horizontally, but I get this issue when I set its adapter:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

*NOTE: I've included some notes in the comments, scroll to the bottom to see them.*

Here is the RecycleView initialization:

```
// I do InitMemberList() in the OnCreate method of my activity
private void InitMemberList()
{
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager =
        new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

    memberRecList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.member_list);
    memberRecList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    memberRecList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    //NOTE 1 (scroll to bottom)
 }
```

My dataset is the ArrayList **members**. I retrieve it from a worker thread using FirebaseDatabase like so:

```
 //this is also in the OnCreate() method, doesn't matter if it's before
 //or after InitMembersList() because it starts a separate thread.
 //I'm showing it just in case I have any errors here
 private void GetMemberInfo(final String userId)
 {
    //NOTE 2 (scroll to bottom)
    //Getting the reference of the database
    DatabaseReference ref = userDB.getReference().getRef();
    Query query = ref.child(userId);
    //Firebase's method names are confusing. These below just retrieve the
    //data from the database ONCE.
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            tempMember = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class); //Getting member info
            members.add(tempMember); //adding member info to the list
            memberCount --; //number of members left to retrieve
            if(memberCount == 0) { 
            //NOTE 3 (scroll to bottom)
            PopulateMemberList(); //the adapter is set inside here
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
     });
}
```

I set **members** adapter in the PopulateMemberList() method like so:

```
private void PopulateMemberList()
{
    MembersListAdapter adapter = new MembersListAdapter(members);
    memberRecList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Here is my custom **MembersListAdapter**:

```
public class MembersListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MembersListAdapter.MemberViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

    public MembersListAdapter(ArrayList<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    public class MemberViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView rep_txt;
        ImageView memberImageView;

        public MemberViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            rep_txt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById((R.id.member_rep_text));
            memberImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.member_profile_image);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return users.size();
    }

    @Override
    public MemberViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //NOTE 4 (scroll to bottom)
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.member_list_item, parent, true);
        return new MemberViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MemberViewHolder holder, int position) {
            final User currentMember = users.get(position);

            //changing the text of my textviews

            //Loading Member Image
            Picasso.with(GroupActivity.this)
                    .load(currentMember.getProfile_picture_ref())
                    .into(holder.memberImage);
    }
```

### **NOTES:**

**NOTE 1:** I tried setting the **memberRecList** adapter as an empty adapter at first inside InitMemberList() and then setting the new adapter once I got the data from Firebase. Didn't work. Gave me the same error.

**NOTE 2:** I use the GetMemberInfo() inside a loop where I pass the **userId** one by one. Firebase gurus will tell me to instead make a foreach loop with dataSnapshot.getChildren() to retrieve users one by one and then filter them, but it's not feasible because of the size of my database. I'd be scanning through a million users just to retrieve 5 of them.

**NOTE 3:** Using **memberCount** to find if member list retrieval is finished allows me to start working with the data *after* it is *fully* retrieved. Without this, trying to access the data gives Nullpointerexception because most of the it can't be received in time.

**NOTE 4:** I'm assuming this is where my error lies? I tried getting the **itemView** parent and then removing **itemView* from it (exactly what the error message says I should do):

```
        @Override
    public MemberViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.member_list_item, parent, true);

        ViewGroup mParent = (ViewGroup) itemView.getParent();
        if(mParent!=null)
            mParent.removeView(itemView);

        return new MemberViewHolder(itemView);
    }
```

but I get a million instances of the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:6688)
```

and then a StackOverflow error and the app crashes:

```
D/Error: ERR: exClass=java.lang.StackOverflowError
D/Error: ERR: exMsg=stack size 8MB
D/Error: ERR: file=ViewGroup.java
D/Error: ERR: class=android.view.ViewGroup
D/Error: ERR: method=resetResolvedLayoutDirection line=6687
D/Error: ERR: stack=java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
```

at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:6687)

Afterwards, the last line is repeated at least 100 times and at the end:

```
D/Error: ERR: TOTAL BYTES WRITTEN: 41276
```

**EDIT:** Forgot to mention, I know FirebaseRecyclerAdapter exists, but I can't use it. If you know of other libraries which could help me, please do tell. Also, would've preferred to use a ListView rather than a RecyclerView, but I need to list the items horizontally (so that I can scroll left/right) and I think that's impossible with ListView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get an `IllegalStateException` because of this:

```
 @Override
    public MemberViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //NOTE 4 (scroll to bottom)
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.member_list_item, parent, true);
        return new MemberViewHolder(itemView);
    }
```

When you inflate a view for a `RecyclerView` you shouldn't add it to its parent, android does it for you.
Change the flag to `false` in the following line to not add view to parent:

```
 View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.member_list_item, parent, false);
```

Comment: Thanks! Setting it to false fixed it! Then that makes this question a duplicate I suppose, because I saw the same error on somebody else's question and the answer exactly said to change the last argument to false. I can't believe I forgot to change it in my code as well. Ugh.

Comment: Glad to help. Don't worry it happens a lot, mostly because even if you don't specify the flag then the default is `true` and you'll still get the exception.